# How do I generate a diff or patch file only showing the differences of the files included in another patch file?

Tags: bash, git, github, diff, patch

I was banging my head into my wall looking for an easy way to do this but couldn't find anything online, so I figured I'd share the solution I came up with.

This is useful for when you need to break apart specific diff files.

Comment: Hi. Cool that you're willing to share this with us, but can you please create an answer and accept it? A lot of people (me included) first check if there's an answer and skip the thread if not. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing! Added (can't accept for two days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while working on a bigger company project that required the issue being broken into multiple tickets, I found myself needing to create separate diff/patch files for each ticket, even though I was working on the same branch with quite a few file changes. Each patch file needed to only contain the differences for specific files, which you can do with:

```
git diff master FILENAME_X FILENAME_Y FILENAME_Z (etc.)
```

but that was quite time consuming to do manually for each file every single time I needed to generate a patch, and it includes the possibility of me forgetting files every time.

The following command will create a diff/patch file of all files included in a different patch file:

```
`cat NAME_OF_INPUT_DIFF.diff | grep "+++" | awk -F "+++ b/" '{if (NR == 1)printf "git diff master " $2; else printf " " $2}'` > NAME_OF_OUTPUT_DIFF.diff
```

The `cat NAME_OF_INPUT_DIFF.diff | grep "+++"` breaks the previous diff into only the lines with the names of files that were added/modified, then `awk -F "+++ b/"` breaks that into just the parsed names of the files, stripping the preceding characters. The rest creates the lengthy git command to generate a diff of specific files, and wrapping it all in backticks makes it be evaluated on execution. Then `> NAME_OF_OUTPUT_DIFF.diff` outputs the resulting diff to a file.

Anyways, I hope this helps someone like it did me! Quite a timesaver.

Comment: Consider turning the backquoted section into its own command: "find names of files mentioned in a diff". Then you can run `git diff $(find-names-of-files existing.diff)` as your shell command, but you can also do `vi $(find-names-of-files existing.diff)` and use it with other programs. This is the Unix "tool" philosophy: write a tool that does one job that plays well with other tools that also do one job, then string the tools together.

Comment: A great deal of the stuff that happens in bash—with `a | b` or `a $(b)`—is all about this tool philosophy; here, you're using grep and awk as tools to build a bigger tool. As you refine the "find file names in a diff" tool you may find better ways to do what you want: for instance, you can drop both cat and grep, as awk itself can do the entire job.